# Pagination in Django-Rest-Framework using API-View

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-pagination

I currently have an API view setup as follows:

```
class CartView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
    api_view = ['GET', 'POST']

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        try:
            cart = request.user.cart
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            cart = Cart.objects.create(user=request.user)
        cart_details = cart.cart_details.all()
        serializer = CartDetailSerializer(cart_details, many=True, fields=['id', 'item', 'quantity', 'product_type'])
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here `CartDetailSerializer` is a normal ModelSerializer.

I want to paginate this API. However, in the docs of DRF, I found this:

> If you're using a regular APIView, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response.

There is no example provided on how to paginate a regular APIView API.

Can anyone post an example which I can use in above scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When using regular APIView, you need to use Django's own Paginator class.

[Django Pagination in Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view)

In your case you can paginate queryset before sending it to serializer.

Something like this:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
    try:
        cart = request.user.cart
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(user=request.user)
    cart_details = cart.cart_details.all()

    paginator = Paginator(cart_details, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        cart_details = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        cart_details = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        cart_details = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    serializer = CartDetailSerializer(cart_details, many=True, fields=['id', 'item', 'quantity', 'product_type'])
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this solution doesn't has the next, previous page link and count in the response.

Answer (score 24):

While the way rayy mentions is a possibility, django-rest-framework can handle this internally with some additional features that make working with your API much easier.  (*note django-rest-framework's pagination is built from the Django paginator from django.core.paginator)

Right after what you quoted is the key information to solving this problem:

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets. If you're using a regular APIView, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response. **See the source code for the mixins.ListMixin and generics.GenericAPIView classes for an example.**

Slight correction to what is stated there: look at the ListModelMixin.

If you go to these two links you can see the source code for the above files:
[generics.py](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py)
[mixins.py](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py)

What you need to do is include something like the following to get pagination to work in the APIView (**note: this code is untested but the idea is correct. There is also a better way of writing this rather than having to include the code in every view but I will leave that up to you to keep my answer short and understandable):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
# if this is where you store your django-rest-framework settings
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .models import Cart 

class CartView(APIView):
    pagination_class = settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        #assuming every other field in the model has a default value    
        cart = Cart.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

        #for a clear example
        cart_details = Cart.objects.all()

        page = self.paginate_queryset(cart_details)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = CartDetailSerializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = CartDetailSerializer(cart_details, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @property
    def paginator(self):
        """
        The paginator instance associated with the view, or `None`.
        """
        if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
            if self.pagination_class is None:
                self._paginator = None
            else:
                self._paginator = self.pagination_class()
        return self._paginator

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
        """
        Return a single page of results, or `None` if pagination is disabled.
        """
        if self.paginator is None:
            return None
        return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        """
        Return a paginated style `Response` object for the given output data.
        """
        assert self.paginator is not None
        return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(data)
```

I hope this was of more help to you and others who come across this post.

Comment: While you are right so is the accepted answer. The DRF pagination merely implements django's built-in pagination. Check out the source code at rest_framework.pagination. Look for the `paginate_queryset` definition

Comment: Excellent addition ryechus.  I hadn't looked at that part of the source code but the backbone of django-rest-framework's pagination is definitely built on the standard Django paginator from django.core.paginator. I edited my previous response.

Comment: Everyting is okay, but it should return page not cart_details,  easy fix:

`if page is not None: serializer = CartDetailSerializer(page, many=True)`
and pagination class coming from DRF with `from rest_framework.settings import api_settings` and `pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS`

Comment: I got this error. 'Settings' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'

What do I  need to do in Setting?

Comment: This answer should help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/35525458/3045403

Comment: Also, if you're returning none like me, make sure to set the default page size in your settings :)

src: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/pagination.py

Answer (score 4):

I prefer extending the Paginator class, here is how it would look:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound as NotFoundError
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination # Any other type works as well
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class CustomPaginator(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10 # Number of objects to return in one page

    def generate_response(self, query_set, serializer_obj, request):
        try:
            page_data = self.paginate_queryset(query_set, request)
        except NotFoundError:
            return Response({"error": "No results found for the requested page"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        serialized_page = serializer_obj(page_data, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serialized_page.data)

class CartView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        cart_details = Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user) # or any other query
        paginator = CustomPaginator()
        response = paginator.generate_response(cart_details, CartDetailSerializer, request)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using DRF version 3.6.2.
You don't need to code so much. Just use this simple steps.

```
 class ProductPagination(PageNumberPagination):
        page_size = 5

    class product_api(generics.ListCreateAPIView):    
            queryset = Products.objects.all()
            serializer_class = product_serilizer
            pagination_class = ProductPagination
```

if you want search functionality by getting method, you can write below code

```
class ProductPagination(PageNumberPagination):
        page_size = 5

class product_api(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Products.objects.all()
    serializer_class = product_serilizer
    pagination_class = SearchProductPagination    

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(product_search_api,self).get_queryset()
        searched_product = self.request.query_params.get('searched_product',None)
        if search:
            qs = Products.objects.filter(Q(product_name__icontains= searched_product))
        return qs
```

Comment: This is not the same case as the OP. ListCreateAPIView class will do the pagination for you, but APIView won't