# Django pagination with next, previous, count

Tags: python, django, pagination

I am trying to do for pagination and reading through this link.

[Pagination in Django-Rest-Framework using API-View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071312/pagination-in-django-rest-framework-using-api-view)

I need to have next, previous url for pagination. Problem is that when I call this one,

```
pagination_class = settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS
```

It say

**'Settings' object has no attribute 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'**

What do I need to import? or install ?

Models.py

```
class CarView(APIView):
permission_classes = ()

def get(self, request):
    """ Get all car """
    car = Car.objects.all()
    # paginator = PageNumberPagination()

    serializer = CarSerializer(car)
    serialized_car = CarSerializer(car, context={"request": request})
    # serializer = CarSerializer(car[0])
    return Response(serialized_car.data)
```

Serializers.py

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

photo_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_photo_url')

class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = ('id','name','price', 'photo_url') 

def get_photo_url(self, car):
    request = self.context.get('request')
    photo_url = car.photo.url
    return request.build_absolute_uri(photo_url)
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {

'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 100,

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':
    ('rest_framework.authentication.OAuth2Authentication',
     'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'),

'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
    'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer',

'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':
('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',)

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your settings file doesn't include a definition for `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS`, it does include a definition for `REST_FRAMEWORK`, and `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS` is part of it.

From [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) documentation on accessing [settings](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#accessing-settings)

> **Accessing settings**
>
> If you need to access the values of REST
>   framework's API settings in your project, you should use the
>   api_settings object. For example.
>
> `from rest_framework.settings import api_settings`
>   `print api_settings.DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`
>
> The api_settings object will check for any user-defined settings, and 
>   otherwise fall
>   back to the default values. Any setting that uses string import paths
>   to refer to a class will automatically import and return the
>   referenced class, instead of the string literal.

You should be able to access `api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS`

Comment: Do you mean I shall change like     pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS ? 

I now got this error. Invalid API setting: 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS'

Comment: @KhantThuLinn did you import `api_settings` like in the example above?

Comment: you mean to import in settings.py? Write this in there? 
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings

Comment: Not in settings.py, where you use `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS`. You should use the import statement `from rest_framework.settings import api_settings`.

Comment: amm still, it it not okay. I already import that and write     pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS. 

I got error like Invalid API setting: 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS

Comment: I too am getting the same error..any ideas why it is occurring?? I have imported the api_settings in views.py also