# Paginator is not showing appropriate result

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to show only 5 results and next 5 in other page.
my view.py

```
class QuestionList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = Question.objects.all()

        paginator = Paginator(res, 5)
        serializer = QuestionSerializers(res, many=True)
        return Response({"Section": serializer.data})
```

how will my paginator work here ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pagination in Django-Rest-Framework using API-View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071312/pagination-in-django-rest-framework-using-api-view)

Comment: how can i add limit and offet in my code

Comment: change your pagination class accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Django-rest provide its own method of pagination. You should use that for instead of building your own. You can find its docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/).

You just have to add following settings in your settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

Data in `ListApiView` will be paginated with this. In your current view

```
class QuestionList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = Question.objects.all()

        page = self.paginate_queryset(res)
        serialized = QuestionSerializers(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serialized.data)
```

Comment: what is comments here ?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typing mistake. Check updated answer.