# how to set pagination in django custom APIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a very simple APIView, but I don't know how to setup pagination here. In this scenario I create a CustomPagination.

pagination_class = CustomPagination works OK when I define queryset at the beginning in `generics.ListAPIView`, for ex. queryset = Event.objects.all() but not with custom get:

views.py:

```
class ProductAPIView(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request):
        pagination_class = CustomPagination
        
        data = Product.objects.filter(status=1)
        product_serializer = ProductSerializers(data,many=True)
        productData=[]

        for record in product_serializer.data:
            value = json.dumps(record)
            temp = json.loads(value)
            _id = temp['id']
            title = temp['title']
            sub_title = temp['sub_title']
            
            productData.append({"id":_id, "title":title, "sub_title":sub_title})

        return Response({"productData":productData})
```

pagination.py:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pagination in Django-Rest-Framework using API-View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071312/pagination-in-django-rest-framework-using-api-view)

Comment: OKAY. how to pass page number in url ?

Comment: you can pass page number as query parameter

Comment: `path('api/get/?page_no', ProductAPIView.as_view(), name='api_get'),`  is it correct?

Comment: You don't have to define the page number in `path()` . just alter the url

Comment: please take a look at this link --> https://pastebin.com/Ppsyb0xt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your views.py should look like this:

```
class ProductAPIView(APIView):
    pagination_class = CustomPagination()

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Product.objects.filter(status=1)
        
        # for pagination
        page = self.pagination_class.paginate_queryset(queryset=queryset, request=request)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = ProductSerializers(page, many=True)
            return self.pagination_class.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = ProductSerializers(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Why are you using this:
if it is done automatically by serializer

```
for record in product_serializer.data:
            value = json.dumps(record)
            temp = json.loads(value)
            _id = temp['id']
            title = temp['title']
            sub_title = temp['sub_title']
            
            productData.append({"id":_id, "title":title, "sub_title":sub_title})
```