# pagination in django rest framework not working

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, response, django-pagination

I have written CustomPagination from drf in a separate file in my project which is like this.

```
class ProductPageNumberPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 1


class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response({
            'links': {
                'next': self.get_next_link(),
                'previous': self.get_previous_link()
            },
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'page_size' : 15,
            'results': data
        })
```

Now I am inheriting it in my view like this:

```
class CouponView(APIView,CustomPagination):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    # pagination_class = CustomPagination


    def get(self,request,pk = None,*args,**kwargs):

        id = pk
        if id is not None:
            abc = Coupons.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = CouponSerializer(abc)
            return serializer.data
        else:
            abc = Coupons.objects.all()           
            serializer = CouponSerializer(abc,many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=200)
```

However, the above code is not working. If I had imported default PageNumberPagination it will work but why inheriting my custom class is not working is my question. Seems like only the default class be inherited and not the custom-defined one.

Comment: Can you  try by setting "pagination_class" with "CustomPagination" instead of inheriting it. Also check, have you defined any default pagination class in settings.py

Comment: setting pagination class in apiview wont work.

Comment: can you try, pagination_class = CustomPagination()

Comment: nope. it creates an object named pagination_class

Comment: try solutions provided here, it might help, not sure.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071312/pagination-in-django-rest-framework-using-api-view

Answer (score 2):

Since you're overriding the `get()` method, you'll need to perform the `paginate_queryset()` as well, before you use the serializer:

```
def get(self,request,pk = None,*args,**kwargs):

        ...
        else:
            abc = self.paginate_queryset(Coupons.objects.all())
            serializer = CouponSerializer(abc,many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to return self.get_paginated_response() instead of Response, like this:

```
class CouponView(APIView,CustomPagination):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    # pagination_class = CustomPagination


    def get(self,request,pk = None,*args,**kwargs):

        id = pk
        if id is not None:
            abc = Coupons.objects.get(id=id)
            serializer = CouponSerializer(abc)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=200)
        else:
            abc = Coupons.objects.all()           
            serializer = CouponSerializer(abc,many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

And I think it should be returned Response in the `if` block instead of raw data.

Comment: The problem of this solution is that you can't attach other attributes, like you would in `Response`, such as headers or status